# PhoneGap's input field looks different than chrome's

Tags: html, ios, cordova

[image: Difference between inputfield look in pc and phonegap on IPad]

This image is not an original snap, i'v took the chrome look and added that extra line that phonegap ( on ipad ) has with gimp( image editor ).

It doesn't happen in the PhoneGap emulator on chrome ( Ripple extension ).

So why is this extra line appears? is there any css property that can make it disappear ?

This is the css that is used:

```
.input_field
{
  font-size:20;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#E2E2E2; 
  border-width:1; 
}
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="input_field" id="system_serial_number" style="width:100%"/>
```

Comment: Thanks amorbytes! it fixed the problem :D

Comment: I am adding comment as a answer please approve it so other can find it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please try this code `input {-webkit-appearance: none;}` in your css file.

if this works, you can find out more about `appearance` css property here

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/